# Pandoc latex to other formats: is there an out-of-the-box way to preserve selected latex commands? (in particular \ref)

Tags: latex, markdown, pandoc

I want to convert old lecture notes from LaTeX to markdown, in order to use them in quarto afterwards. I would like to preserve the raw LaTeX references, `\ref{some-label}` and possibly also other raw LaTeX commands. Is there a canonical way to do that, or should I write a filter?

Minimal example: `pandoc minimal.tex -o minimal.md`

with
`minimal.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Refer to \textbf{example} \ref{example1}, blabla
\end{document}
```

gives
`minimal.md`

```
Refer to **example** [\[example1\]](#example1){reference-type="ref"
reference="example1"}, blabla
```

but I want

```
Refer to **example** \ref{example1}, blabla
```

p.s. The reason why I want to preserve references is, that I want to use my own filter to resolve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `raw_tex` extension will cause all unknown or difficult to convert TeX commands to be passed through as raw elements:

```
% pandoc --from=latex+raw_tex minimal.tex
Refer to **example** `\ref{example1}`{=latex}, blabla
```

Filtering on `RawInline` and `RawBlock` elements then allows to process these elements in whatever way you see fit.

Comment: Cool! So I still need a filter, but don't need to search all strings. Are *difficult* TeX commands defined anywhere? Guess that list is shrinking over time..  Or can I even add to the list of commands I want to preserve? A hack could consist in undefining commands prior to pandocking?

Comment: There's no list, unfortunately. The best method to ensure that a command isn't converted is probably to redefine it; e.g., adding `\def\textbf{\mytextbf}` would make sure that none of the `\textbf` commands are converted to boldface by pandoc, resulting in a raw `\mytextbf` instead. Should also work with environments (`\renewenvironment`).

Comment: yes, that is a smart way to "undefine" the macros. One could write a pair of filters for that ;-)